# how to convert a given video file to all possible codec/container format combinations

Tags: ffmpeg, transcode

I posted the same question in [Video Production StackExchange site](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34142/how-to-convert-a-given-video-file-to-all-possible-codec-container-format-combina) 8 days and there is not even a single answer to that up till now. So now I decided to try my luck here in Superuser site.

My semi-smart LCD TV supports USB. I have a couple of video files on my laptop which I want to run on that big LCD TV, through a USB stick. The problem is that when I attach a USB stick containing my videos, the TV does not display anything but I can hear the audio of the videos which means the TV supports the audio codec or the container but not the video container or the codec. This is not-a-big-brand TV from some Chinese company which I bought 2nd hand and I was unable to find its documentation online, at least on English websites. Now I don't know which video codecs and container combinations this TV supports.

I know how to use `ffmpeg` command line tool for basic transcoding e.g. converting an AVI file to MP4 without re-encoding etc. But I don't know how can I use it to generate all the possible output format/container combinations it can support. The idea is to generate all the possible codec+container combinations, copy them on a USB stick and then try to run them on the TV. I hope it will support at least one of them.

If this is impossible through `ffmpeg`, is there any other software which can do this? In case that helps, I have access to both, Mac OS and Windows machines so I am open to any solution.

Comment: Not a good idea. Find your TV specs and convert the video accordingly.

Comment: Could be considered a duplicate of [Re-encoding videos for 10year old Panasonic TV-set](https://superuser.com/a/1561653/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a batch script to run all the different commands:
For example, I use python here:

```
import subprocess #used to run commands
formats = ["mp4", "avi"] #put all your formats you want here
input_file = "example.file" #replace this name with your original file
for f in formats: #loop all formats you gave in the list
    subprocess.call(f"ffmpeg -i {input_file} output.{f}") #run the commands
```

The files get saved as "output.your_format"

Comment: Those are only container formats. There's codecs, too. Not every codec works (well) in every container etc., this is a very complicated topic and there won't be an easy solution.